# How to update the nested_attributes with json in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I have

```
 class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :samples
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :samples
 end
```

and

```
 class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tests
 end
```

Now when i create new value as follows

> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'
>   -X POST `http://localhost:3000/tests.json` -d "{\"test\":{\"name\":\"xxxxxx\",
>   \"samples_attributes\":[{\"username\":\"yyyyyyy\",\"age\":\"25\"}]}}"

it creates a new value for the test and it also creates an entry in the **`sample`** table but when updating it updates the test table whereas it creates a new entry in the sample table. so how can i make it to update the present entry?

please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the `id` in the hash for update records ([view API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :posts   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

If the hash contains an `id` key that matches an already associated record, the matching record will be modified:

```
member.attributes = {
  name: 'Joe',
  posts_attributes: [
    { id: 1, title: '[UPDATED] An, as of yet, undisclosed awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { id: 2, title: '[UPDATED] other post' }
  ]
}
```

For each hash that does not have an `id` key a new record will be instantiated.

```
params = { member: {
  name: 'joe', posts_attributes: [
    { title: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { title: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' }
  ]
}}
```

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. I tried that earlier and it worked and forgot to post the answer. Anyways thankyou.